# Is there a way I could convert GWT RPC response into a readable format?

Tags: gwt, jmeter, load-testing, gwt-rpc

I have a large scale GWT Application and I wanted to perform load testing on it. After trying jmeter and a lot of plugins with it I finally thought I should instead figure out how to make the RPC response readable so that I can use the response along with Regular Expression Extractor to proceed with my testing instead of using the plugins. So is there a way I could convert the response into readable format?

Here is a sample response:

```
//OK[2,1,["com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlString/235635043","Hello, 
Hello!<br>I am running jetty-6.1.x.<br><br>It looks like you are using: 
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"],0,7]
```

I am more interested in doing so for GWT 2.8+ Applications whereas almost all the sources found online give information on the older versions.

Comment: is there a reason for not contacting our support in another question you asked ? thanks

Comment: My team will do that through a proper channel shortly. Meanwhile I am trying to learn how deserialization works. Thank you. @ubik-load-pack

Comment: it does look readable, what's the problem with it? what are you trying to extract?

Comment: This example might seem readable but there are cases when the request and the response is so big that you cannot figure out anything with it. Sorry for this example it might be super easy to read but its just an example. What I am more interested in is converting it to something like an XML or any other similar format. @kiril-s

Comment: if what you posted is a typical pattern (regardless of the size) then other than `//OK`, it's a perfectly valid JSON, which you could parse using JSON path post-processor, which is similar to XML path post-processor. SO ditching `//OK`might be the only thing you need to do.

Comment: Did you try googling this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211232/deserialize-server-response